# ¿Como colocar contenido de una base de datos mysql en HTML?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

¿Cómo hacer para colocar los datos de una base de datos *MySQL* sin hacer el recorrido?, es decir lo que quiero hacer es sacar un valor por valor. Quería saber si esto se puede hacer, o se debe utilizar por reglamento el ciclo para recorrer.

la idea de sacar valor por valor es para colocarlo en distintas partes del html.

Aquí tengo mi conexion a mysql

```
<?php 
require 'funciones.php';

$conexion = conexion('galeria_practica', 'root', '');

if(!$conexion){
    
    die('error en el sistema');
}
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM fotos');
    $statement->execute();
    $resultado = $statement->fetchALL();
    // $fotos = count($resultado);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($resultado);
    echo "</pre>";


require 'views/index.view.php';

?>
```

Con esto ya me aparece bien en el navegador el erreglo de las imágenes, en total, tengo 19 imágenes.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [0] => 1
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 1.jpg
            [2] => 1.jpg
            [texto] => sddsdsd
            [3] => sddsdsd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [0] => 2
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 2.jpg
            [2] => 2.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [0] => 3
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 3.jpg
            [2] => 3.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [0] => 4
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 4.jpg
            [2] => 4.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 5.jpg
            [2] => 5.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [0] => 6
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 6.jpg
            [2] => 6.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [0] => 7
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 7.jpg
            [2] => 7.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [0] => 8
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 8.jpg
            [2] => 8.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [0] => 9
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 9.jpg
            [2] => 9.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [0] => 10
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 10.jpg
            [2] => 10.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [0] => 11
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 11.jpg
            [2] => 11.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [0] => 12
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 12.jpg
            [2] => 12.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [0] => 13
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 13.jpg
            [2] => 13.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 14
            [0] => 14
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 14.jpg
            [2] => 14.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [0] => 15
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 15.jpg
            [2] => 15.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [0] => 16
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => 16.jpg
            [2] => 16.jpg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 17
            [0] => 17
            [titulo] => 
            [1] => 
            [imagen] => WhatsApp Image 2021-01-28 at 7.51.47 PM.jpeg
            [2] => WhatsApp Image 2021-01-28 at 7.51.47 PM.jpeg
            [texto] => 
            [3] => 
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [0] => 18
            [titulo] => hugo
            [1] => hugo
            [imagen] => WhatsApp Image 2021-02-01 at 1.46.02 PM.jpeg
            [2] => WhatsApp Image 2021-02-01 at 1.46.02 PM.jpeg
            [texto] => hugo villalba
            [3] => hugo villalba
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [0] => 19
            [titulo] => Imagen
            [1] => Imagen
            [imagen] => img255.jpg
            [2] => img255.jpg
            [texto] => Imagen de prueba
            [3] => Imagen de prueba
        )

)
```

Tengo este código hecho con el framework de bootstrap 4.0, pero no se como hacer para que se me vea así, igual cuando coloque las imágenes de la base de datos.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="fotos/1.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="fotos/2.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="fotos/3.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        </div><br>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="fotos/4.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="fotos/5.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><a href="#"><img src="fotos/6.jpg" alt=""></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Y que [intentastes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4884)?

Comment: Si tu base de datos está funcionando en el mismo sistema que tu aplicación PHP, dale una mirada a la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli)

Comment: Hola, lo que yo quiero hacer es como modificar toda mi pagina web desde la base de datos. como colocar todo lo que tengo en la base de datos pasarlo al framework de bootstrap. si me hago entender.

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. El código va como texto, así como nadie te va a responder con imágenes para ponerte a transcribir. Por favor, edita la pregunta.